# Where to find the old default Photoshop brushes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I am looking for the default brushes from older Photoshop versions. Where can I get them?

I am particularly interested in brushes 112 and 134 from the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: the best way to say "thank you" is to mark the most helpful answer as "Accepted". Check [ask] if you want more info on how the site works.

Comment: @Luciano his last seen is 10+ days ago :P seems he found his solution!

Comment: @Mr.Online since OP is a new-ish user I'm nudging them into learning how to use the site.

Comment: I was just saying that there will be rare species who only comes to find answer and once it's given they will be invicible :) so that's what I mean that he might be that one but who knows he'll be surprised when he eventually come to ask another question and finding out that his question got popular lol! and yeah keep up the *GOOD* work man ♥

Answer (score 15):

**Yes!  it's in by default but just hidden**

- Select Brush by either brush tool or <kbd>b</kbd>
- Right click to open brush manager, on top right corner you'll find little gear.
- From there select ***"Legacy Brushes"*** and boom your brushes will be restored! You can find them in *Default Brushes* under folder names *Legacy brushes*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually select **Windows > Brush Presets**

- **Brush Presets** Dialog Right click on top corner to select **Preset Manager**
- From **Preset Manager** select your specified brush type 112, 134 and **load**
- Loaded brushes will be seen now.

Below screenshot for your reference.

[image]